# Ruby on Rails Trouble - rake-12.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, rake

Anytime I try running the following basic rails commands, e.g. rails g model or rails console, I encounter the following error;

Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.

I've already looked through the forums for solutions and haven't found anything that solves my problem.

My gem file includes the necessary gem and I already ran bundle install.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `bundle exec ruby bin/rails g ...` or similar. Then run `which ruby`, `which gem`, and `which rake`, edit your post and add the results. Then confess which system you used to install Ruby - compiled, an OS distribution package, `rvm`, or `rbenv`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have two versions of rake instaled.
Sometimes you have two rails projects with different rake versions and you did bundle install in one and after in another. (now you have two rake versions)

try `gem uninstall rake`

This command above will show you two these rake versions. You have to type the number that you want to unistall.